# How can you make a java object override its methods?

Tags: java, methods, overriding

Here's what I'm thinking. So lets say I have a class called intro and I want to do something when it starts and finishes. I'm wondering how could I do something like this:

```
public Main(){
    //Calls the object that overrides its own methods
    new Intro(){
        @Override
        public void onStartIntro(){
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinishIntro(){
        }
    }
```

What would need to happen in the Intro class to enable something like this?

Comment: What does "when it starts and finishes" mean? When what starts and finishes? When it's constructed and destroyed?

Comment: Well, the intro example was arbitrary. I needed to know how I could get the code I posted above to work. Apparently calling the class abstract will do just that. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just create an abstract class to force overriding of the methods (but a non-abstract class with non-final methods will also do)

```
abstract class Intro
{
    abstract void onStartIntro();
    abstract void onFinishIntro();
}
```

Comment: Of create a concrete class that has these defined and are not final, but +1 for a short, simple answer.

Comment: Wow that was much simpler than I thought. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Something like this:

```
public class Main(){
    public Main(){
        new Intro();
    }


    private class Intro extends SomeOtherClass{
        @Override
        public void onStartIntro(){ /*...Code...*/ }

        @Override
        public void onFinishIntro(){ /*...Code...*/ }
    }

}
```

Intro would only be available inside your "Main" class...